# How do Git revisions and references relate to each other?

Tags: git

In the end, both revisions and references are pointers to Git objects so what is the point in having both?

Comment: What is your question? It seems like you answered your question many times over.

Comment: I'm torn between upvoting and downvoting. There isn't an actual question, OTOH your "question" would serve as a great answer to some of the questions I've seen here. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## TL;DR
>
> A **Git reference** (i.e., the alternative name of a Git object) can be a **Git revision** (i.e., a Git object query)<sup>**example-1**,</sup>, but not vice versa<sup>**example-2**</sup> because:
>
> - (MANY-TO-ONE) A `ref` can only stand for a **single** Git object, but each Git object can have many `ref`s.
> - (ONE-TO-MANY) A `rev` can resolve to one or more Git objects.
>
> <sup>[example-1]: `git log main`</sup>
> <sup>[example-2]: [`git log main..topic`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot) (even though the revision `main..topic` uses two references, `main` and `topic`).</sup>

#### Git references (`ref`s)

> **Many-to-one** relationship between:
>
> ```
> ┌─────────┐             ┌──────┐
> │  Git    │ *         1 │  Git │
> │reference├────────────►│object│
> └─────────┘             └──────┘
> ```
>
> **Git reference** points to a singular **Git object**<sup>**2**</sup>, and multiple **Git references** can point
> to the same **Git object**.

To belabor the point:

- A [Git reference](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) is an alternative designation<sup>**1**</sup> of a particular Git object<sup>**2**</sup>.
- When a [Git reference](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) is de-referenced (or resolved), the result is one [SHA-1 object name (40-byte hexadecimal string)](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#:%7E:text=SHA%2D1%20object%20name%20(40%2Dbyte%20hexadecimal%20string))<sup>**3**</sup> identifying a [Git object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) in the object database.
- [Git references](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) and Git objects<sup>**2**</sup> are in a **many-to-one** relationship: many references can point to the same object, but a reference can only point a single object at any given time.

<sup>[1]: Or "alias", "pointer", "label", etc.</sup>
<sup>[2]: There are 4 Git object types: [tree, blob, commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), and [tag](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#_tags).</sup>
<sup>[3]: [For now](https://git-scm.com/docs/hash-function-transition/), at least.</sup>

For example:

```
[~/my-project]$ git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects
10d5ab2b502faadff680c6904cbd60d7a8b5d0af tree 34
11f61d01b7af5c657c13109777a577ef6a3d3a7a tree 34
1d41fcffd528c1ee950b630d939407fe5f3b22d0 tree 34
40267b7fcf0d4490a45e0d70618a5d7b63895a60 blob 25
5a6bdceda9ae20b80fed214776b4423f522f2d01 tree 68
5b76730490981c045b186fd9651f91f0492c5b07 blob 12
5f45e9c854941c72deb9d36fb3e95e4feb4d698f commit 234
64a77169fe44d06b082cbe52478b3539cb333d45 tree 34
6692c9c6e231b1dfd5594dd59b32001b70060f19 commit 237
740481b1d3ce7de99ed26f7db6687f83ee221d67 blob 50
83cb3ab54ca122d439bdd9997a21f399cac69692 blob 16
864333c0eccabdaba6df27166ac616c922569b47 blob 42
abb08192ed875ef73fa66029994aa2f6700befd0 commit 231
c277976fce0b2b32b954a66d4345730b5b08f1db commit 230
e67cb07f9ddb0ecd0f88fcf36093d8d8bf928b75 commit 175
e95dd8284a84af5418c0dcf9cbdc0b1061624907 blob 25

[~/my-project]$ git show-ref --head --dereference
5f45e9c854941c72deb9d36fb3e95e4feb4d698f HEAD
c277976fce0b2b32b954a66d4345730b5b08f1db refs/heads/main
5f45e9c854941c72deb9d36fb3e95e4feb4d698f refs/heads/topic
c277976fce0b2b32b954a66d4345730b5b08f1db refs/remotes/origin/main
5f45e9c854941c72deb9d36fb3e95e4feb4d698f refs/remotes/origin/topic
e95dd8284a84af5418c0dcf9cbdc0b1061624907 refs/tags/balabab
e95dd8284a84af5418c0dcf9cbdc0b1061624907 refs/tags/lofa
5f45e9c854941c72deb9d36fb3e95e4feb4d698f refs/tags/miez
```

[image]

#### Git revisions (`rev`s)

> **One-to-many** relationship between
>
> ```
> ┌────────┐              ┌──────┐
> │  Git   │ 1          * │  Git │
> │revision├──────────────┤object│
> └────────┘              └──────┘
> ```
>
> A **Git revision** is a Git object query that resolves to one or more **Git object**s.

A Git revision is a string of characters conforming to [a special notation syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) - or "[revision query system](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#:%7E:text=This%20makes%20for%20a%20very%20powerful%20revision%20query%20system%20that%20should%20help%20you%20figure%20out%20what%20is%20in%20your%20branches)" - that are used to unambiguously select one or more Git objects<sup>**2**</sup>.

This is akin how database systems (e.g., PostgreSQL) use a query language (e.g., SQL), but in this case Git is the database system and the revision syntax is the query language. The analogy seems apt to the extent to revisions being [able to refer to a range of Git objects](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_ranges) too.

For example, given this commit history,

```
* ebc9079 (HEAD -> main) karikittyom
* 982b806 edes
* ccccccc tyukom
* bbbbbbb megis van
* aaaaaaa egy felpenzem
```

the revision `aaaaaaa..ccccccc` will return commits `bbbbbbb` and `ccccccc`:

```
$ git log aaaaaaa..ccccccc

commit cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
Author: toraritte
Date:   Mon Jan 9 03:29:24 2023 +0000

    tyukom

commit bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
Author: toraritte
Date:   Mon Jan 9 03:29:24 2023 +0000

    megis van
```

#### The connection between `ref`s and `rev`s

*Git **references** are simply labels for specific Git objects*, but there are plenty of times when one would like to carry out operations on other objects as well. The only way to do it without revisions is to manually find them and then list all the SHA-1 hashes of the Git objects involved.

*The **revision** notation is a query system to reach any Git object (or a range of them) in a repo* by traversing the directed acyclic graph or DAG.

The fundamental building blocks of relative<sup>**5**</sup> **revision queries** are

- [extended SHA-1 syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltsha1gtemegemdae86e1950b1277e545cee180551750029cfe735ememdae86eem) (e.g., `<sha1>`, e.g. `dae86e1950b1277e545cee180551750029cfe735`, `dae86e`)
- [Git references](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) (which ultimately resolve to `<sha1>`)

where **references** serve as starting points to begin traversing the graph.

<sup>[5]: The use of "relative" is important here, because there are also [`:/<text>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem) and [`:\[<n>:\]<path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem) that require no anchor.</sup>

At least, every notation from the [`gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) docs boil down to the above conclusion:

- > `<describeOutput>`, e.g. `v1.7.4.2-679-g3bee7fb`
  > [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) "*finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit*". Tags are Git references, and `git describe` already has its own revision-esque notation for its results.
- > `[<branchname>]@{upstream}`, e.g. `master@{upstream}`, `@{u}`
  > [Branch names are Git references](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#:%7E:text=That%E2%80%99s%20basically%20what%20a%20branch%20in%20Git%20is%3A%20a%20simple%20pointer%20or%20reference%20to%20the%20head%20of%20a%20line%20of%20work), and the rest is the revision query notation.
- > `<rev>^{<type>}`, e.g. `v0.99.8^{commit}`
  > Where `<rev>` means to "[*dereference the object at  recursively*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#:%7E:text=dereference%20the%20object%20at%20%3Crev%3E%20recursively)", so in the end we'll get to a tag or `<sha1>`.

Comment: Besides the above, some references are constrained: branch names must store commit hash IDs. All references are weakly constrained to contain valid hash IDs, but there's little checking for this except when you ask Git to create the ref (Git will try to find a valid hash ID at that time).

Answer (score 3):

> ... and that's it (?).

And that's it... almost.

Git uses the filesystem as its database. References are stored in one of two places. `.git/refs` and `.git/packed-refs`.

`.git/refs/` contains a file for each reference. For example, the main branch is in `.git/refs/heads/main`. The tag v1.2.3 is in `.git/refs/tags/v1.2.3`. The file contains the SHA of the commit it references. When you ask for `main`, git searches these directories and when it finds a filename that matches it reads the SHA from the file. Simple. This is why you can also refer to the main branch as `main`, `heads/main`, and `refs/heads/main`; they're just relative file paths to search.

Searching a directory tree gets unwieldy if there are many references and doesn't scale, especially on network drives. So git will occasionally "pack" these references into a single file, `.git/packed-refs`. This is a simple file with one line for each reference and the format `<sha> <ref>`. Git opens the file, reads until it finds a matching reference, and uses its sha.

Such a small and frequently referenced file will likely remain in the operating system's cache making subsequent reads very fast. New references go into `.git/refs/` to avoid having to rewrite the whole packfile every time; Git will write a new packfile periodically.

It's a very fast, very elegant, and very portable solution to use the filesystem as its database rather than something like SQLite or a binary file format.

You can read more about [packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) and [references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) in the [Git Internals](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) chapter of Pro Git.